# Return from an IF statement inside of a react render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to add components to the DOM by adding them to an array on click. 
To differentiate which component to add to the array for render; I am using an if statement to match to the state but I cannot use return here because it would return nothing. 
Can anyone help me with a solution to either return from the if statement once matched or combine the existing return into the if statement.

### Below is my app containing the if statement

```
import React from 'react';
import ModuleOne from './moduleOne';
import ModuleTwo from './moduleTwo';
import ParentComponent from './parentComponent';
const Module1 = props => <ModuleOne />;
const Module2 = props => <ModuleTwo />;
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    numChildren: 0,
    doubleContent: false
    //tripleContent: false
  }
  isSingleContent = () => {
    this.setState({
      numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1
    });
  }
  isDoubleContent = () => {
    this.setState({
      doubleContent: true,
      numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1
    });
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.doubleContent == true) {
      this.setState(
        { doubleContent: false }
      );
    }
  }
  render() {
    const mods = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
      if (this.state.doubleContent) {
        mods.push(<Module2 key={i} number={i} />);
      }
      else {
        mods.push(<Module1 key={i} number={i} />);
      }
    };
    return (
      <ParentComponent singleContent={this.isSingleContent} doubleContent={this.isDoubleContent}>
        {mods}
      </ParentComponent>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

### And the parent component

Containing the buttons and the viewport the array is embedded to.

```
import React from 'react';
const ParentComponent = props => (
    <div id="app">
        <a href="#" onClick={props.singleContent}>Add single</a><br/>
        <a href="#" onClick={props.doubleContent}>Add double</a>
        <div id="viewport">
            {props.children}
        </div>
    </div>
);
export default ParentComponent;
```

Comment: Where do you want to return and what is the expected result?

Comment: @Emile Bergeron - Inside of the App class render function there is an if statement. The problem is that because the statement sits within the render I cannot return from the statement because that would return nothing. This means that the if statement is processed but then continues to the else. Which means the else is always the result. The result I need is to stop flowing into the else if the if statement is met.

Comment: Do you mean break; statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a particular reason *to* return here, unless you were planning on moving this code to a method.  Even then you wouldn't want to return because you want to continue through the entire list.  I'm a bit lost as to why you want to return out.

Part of a problem I can see, you are doubling no matter what or not doubling.  It's not really a case by case situation for your code, so there's not much point to having your if statement in your loop.  I've also used es6 map to reduce the code a bit.

```
let mods = [];
if(this.state.doubleNum){
    mods = this.state.numChildren.map( (num, index)=> <Module2 key={index} number={i} />
} else {
    mods = this.state.numChildren.map( (num, index)=> <Module1 key={index} number={i} />
}
```

Now a few things.  First, you really shouldn't use the index for the key, this can [confuse react](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Secondly, I would probably move the functionality into a separate method to reduce confusion.

Thirdly, and this one I am fuzzy on, but there is likely a way to specify the name of the component a bit more dynamically rather than making a clumsy if statement, but the method escapes me at the moment, though [this might be the right approach](https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/dynamic-tag-names-in-react-and-jsx-17e366a684e9).

Comment: even `const ModuleComponent = this.state.doubleNum ? Module2 : Module1;` would be enough.

Comment: indeed, though does it pass along props using that method?

Comment: You then pass props to `ModuleComponent`, regardless of the component it really is behind. `<ModuleComponent key={index} number={i} />`

Comment: It avoids repeating the mapping. Though it would not work as well if one of the component would take significantly different props.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @EmileBergeron!

Comment: So then you would do something like:

`const ModuleComponent = this.state.doubleNum ? Module2 : Module1;`

`const mods = this.state.numChildren.map( (index, number) => ModuleComponent);`
?

Comment: It's still needed to use the component like any other component in JSX: `const mods = this.state.numChildren.map((index, number) => <ModuleComponent key={index} number={i} />);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `double: true` in your state, why not have a `type` property instead, and switch between 'single' and 'double' when you click the buttons:

```js
function ModuleOne() {
  return <div>Module One</div>;
}

function ModuleTwo() {
  return <div>Module Two</div>;
}

function ParentComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div id="app">
        <button type="button" onClick={props.singleContent}>Add single</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={props.doubleContent}>Add double</button>
        <div id="viewport">
            {props.children}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    numChildren: 0,
    type: undefined
  }

  isSingleContent = () => {
    this.setState({
      type: 'single',
      numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1
    });
  }

  isDoubleContent = () => {
    this.setState({
      type: 'double',
      numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1
    });
  }

  render() {
    const mods = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
      if (this.state.type === 'double') {
        mods.push(<ModuleTwo key={i} number={i} />);
      }
      else {
        mods.push(<ModuleOne key={i} number={i} />);
      }
    };
    return (
      <ParentComponent
        singleContent={this.isSingleContent}
        doubleContent={this.isDoubleContent}
      >{mods}
      </ParentComponent>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```